# Hibernate DiscriminatorValue equivalent in Doctrine 2

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, discriminator

I got a question. I have been waiting on the **DiscriminatorColumn** annotation in **Doctrine 2** but now that I got it via Update of Doctrine I am not able to find the **Hibernate's** **DiscriminatorValue** annotation equivalent in Doctrine. FYI, my Doctrine version is "doctrine/orm": "^2.5.6" and "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.6" but I cannot find such annotation.

My basic desire here is to set the Discriminator Column value per child class not in the main class in the **DiscriminatorMap**.

Comment: I solved this for myself a while back. Have a read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015356/zf2-doctrine-2-child-level-discriminators-with-class-table-inheritance. Not quite sure what you mean with "hibernate" though?...

Comment: Well, I mean the Java Hibernate ORM - http://hibernate.org/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like my comment stated, I had this issue a while back as well, where I wanted to "declare" new DiscriminatorMap entries on the child-classes. The short answer is: **do not declare a map at all**. Doctrine takes care of it.

Have a read of my [full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015356/zf2-doctrine-2-child-level-discriminators-with-class-table-inheritance). This works for me using [Class Table Inheritance (CTI)](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance), the docs state that it should work the same for [Single Table Inheritance (STI)](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance).

The basic code setup to let Doctrine handle it for you is:

```
<?php
namespace My\Namespace\Entity;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("JOINED")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * // NOTE: No DiscriminatorMap!!!
 */
class Person
{
    // ...
}


<?php
namespace My\Other\Namespace\Entity;

/** @Entity */
class Employee extends \My\Namespace\Entity\Person
{
    // ...
}
```